# Lua Script match multiple word

Tags: regex, nginx, lua, openresty, lua-patterns

My first time, I try Lua script, I want to match on string (user-Agent), multiple substring to exclude them when it is match.

pattern string is User-Agent pattern, and the multiple string are google, safari and edge

```
 local m, err = ngx.re.match(ngx.req.get_headers()['User-Agent'], "(*google*|*safari*|*edge*)", "io")
    if not m
    then
      ..
    end
```

The problem User-Agent contain google, safari, edge string is still present on my request.

For instance User-Agent :

```
Mozilla/5.0 (**google**; CPU iPhone OS 14_4 like Mac OS X) 
Mozilla/5.0 (**safari**; CPU iPhone OS 15_1 like Mac OS X) 
Timescode_RESTClient **edge** alpha
```

I want to exclude them.

Comment: This looks like your using a `regex` library in lua not a `lua-pattern`, is that correct?

Comment: yes it is thats

Comment: Any help please ?

Comment: What do you mean by "edge string is still present on my request"? You aren't doing anything with your request, and your regex looks invalid (ngx.re uses PCRE expressions) - I'm guessing that `err` contains an error message

Comment: I mean , the requests with User-Agent still match on regex, and I cannot exclude them, so my regex is not correct

Answer (score 0):

[`ngx.re.match`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxrematch) uses PCRE regular expressions where `*` means roughly "zero or more repetitions of whatever is before it", so you must escape it: `(\*google\*|\*safari\*|\*edge\*)`